# Selected added item in TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I have and *Add* button and `TableViewer` in my application. When the *Add* button is pressed, I'm adding a new element to my model, then refreshing that viewer.

The question is: How to select this newly added item in my viewer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tableViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(modelElement), true);
```

The `true` at the end will make the table scroll to the newly selected item, if necessary.